# Keycloak authentication on Google Sheet Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We are working on integrating our integrating our REST Project with google sheet. This project has keycloak authentication (Basic Authentication). We are trying to achieve something like following

1. Adding a menu in google sheet.
2. Clicking on this menu, keycloak login page should open
3. Once user enters username and password and clicks on login, it should get redirected to google sheet again with the token.

I tried finding way but could not achieve. is there any way to achieve the same ?

Comment: I thought that your process might be able to be achieved using Google Apps Script. But I cannot understand about `it should get redirected to google sheet again with the token.`. So I cannot image your goal. I apologize for this. How will you use the retrieved token for Google Spreadsheet? Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, I thought that about the basic authorization for Google Apps Script, you can see it from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+Basic+Authentication&s=d258f80b-5458-417b-afc2-bac01d5b65aa

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Thanks for your response. We have an existing system which has keycloak based authentication. This system has certain REST end points which we want to invoke from google sheets. So for that we want a kind of mechanism where we can open the keycloak login page in google sheet and then user can log in to that. once user logs in, we can get token in google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood your goal as follows. You wanted to retrieve the token on Google Spreadsheet and you wanted to use the retrieved token with other HTTP request. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, your goal can be achieved using Google Apps Script.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes that is my goal. but the application i am trying to access is web based and it has keycloak based authentication. So if i want to access any points of that web application, i need authentication token. So if i can achieve something like opening a browser from google sheet, login to the application and token will be send to google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your question, it seems that "keycloak authentication" is "Basic Authentication". I think that this might be able to be used. In this case, how about showing a custom dialog for retrieving the user name and password for the user and retrieving the token using UrlFetchApp? But I couldn't still understand about your goal for using the retrieved token. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about it?